# Trying to pass data from Express backend to React frontend with Axios, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios

I'm trying to pass data from Express backend to React frontend with Axios, but It doesn't work. The data I'm trying to pass comes from a text file.

Backend:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

var fs = require('fs')
var data1 = fs.readFileSync('./inputs/category1.txt', 'utf8')
var textByLine1 = data1.split('\r\n')
var data2 = fs.readFileSync('./inputs/category2.txt', 'utf8')
var textByLine2 = data2.split('\n')


console.log(textByLine1)

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.send(textByLine1)
})
app.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log("express server is running on port 3001");
})
```

Axios:

```
import axios from 'axios';


export type ApiClient = {
    getProperties: (c:number) => Promise<string[]>;
}

/** get tickets with search and page queries */
export const createApiClient = (): ApiClient => {
    return {
        getProperties: async (c:number) => {
            const res = await axios.get('/', { params: { category: c} });
            return res.data;
        }
    }
}

export default createApiClient
```

React frontend:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {createApiClient} from './api'; //connection to server


export type AppState = {
  flow: number,
  category_index: number,
  categories: string[],
}

const api = createApiClient()

export class App extends React.PureComponent<{}, AppState> {

  state: AppState = {
        flow: 1,
    category_index: 2,
    categories:[]
    }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
            categories: await api.getProperties(this.state.flow)
        });
    console.log(this.state.categories)

  }
  
  render() {
    return( 
    <main>    
      <div>  
      <button>click me</button>
      </div>
    </main>
    )
  }

}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to pass the list of strings from the backend to the frontend, than console.log it to see that it was actually passed. instead, I see the following in the console:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I think that means I'm getting "empty" in the axios.get(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not actually making the request to the API, so the dev server returns index.html to allow the SPA to do client-side routing.

Comment: Thanks so much :) Why am not making the request? How can change this?

Comment: I don't know why you're not making the request to the API; it's unclear why you thought `.get('/', ...)` _would_ do that, given that it's obviously a request to the same endpoint that just gave you the React app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call your API, you’ll need to call the URL that your API is serving, which I believe is `http://localhost:3001/`.

Try this:

```
const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/', { params: { category: c} });
```